# How to get the attachment ID in JIRA

Tags: java, rest, jira

I want to delete the attachments in JIRA using REST service in JAVA.

restTemplate.delete("http://issusteackingsomething/jira/rest/api/2/attachment/{id})

I need to have the attachment ID from JIRA for the attachment to be deleted.
How do i get that attachment ID?

Answer (score 1):

Use:
https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/cloud/#api/2/issue-getIssue

This is simple URL-requst. Use URL:
http://"Your_domain_jira"/rest/api/2/issue/"Issue ID or Issue Key"

Parse responce json and you find all information about attachments, like that:
"attachment":[{"self":"what ever link", "id":"some sort of id that you need"} ]

Answer (score 0):

You have to know issue key in order to understand to which issue attachment belongs. It can be done in DB or using rest api call:

http://issusteackingsomething/jira/rest/api/latest/issue/ISSUEKEY

In case of REST API call you will have to parse output:

"attachment": [
            {
                "self": 
                "id": "1074703",
                "filename": "",
                "author": {